# TYPO3 Gridelement nesting not working

Tags: typo3, tx-gridelements

I've created a extension based on bootstrap_grids, but cannot nest the grid elements. I understand that "allowed = *" should do the job, but the ce don't show up in nested elements.

```
tx_gridelements {
    setup {
        section {
            title = LLL:EXT:h_grid/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:section.title
            description = LLL:EXT:h_grid/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:section.description
            icon = EXT:h_grid/Resources/Public/Icons/gridlayout_section.gif
            frame = 3
            topLevelLayout = 0
            config {
                colCount = 1
                rowCount = 1
                rows.1 {
                    columns {
                        1 {
                            name = LLL:EXT:h_grid/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:celayout.leftColumn
                            colPos = 101
                            allowed = *
                            allowedGridTypes = *
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ....
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't really know what's going on, but what happens if you remove allowed and allowedGridTypes since you're not restricting the allowed values anyways?

Comment: Thanks. Real strange behavior here. When I remove the lines it really works as you mentioned. But shouldn't it also work with "allowed = *"? As soon as I add "allowed = *" all available elements show up but not the grid elements.

Comment: I guess it should. I've only ever used it with actual elements listed and left out that line when I didn't want to exclude any, that's why I suggested to try it out. I'll add this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try leaving out the lines

```
allowed = *
allowedGridTypes = *
```

when you're not actually excluding any elements.